# IOS app closes on map zoomedout to maximum value

Tags: ios, crash, zooming, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on an ios app using ti.map module(titanium),the problem im facing here is when i **zoomout** of the map page **completely** the **app closes itself**.please sugguest how can I solve this issue,is there anything like setting **minimum/maximum zoom level for ios to zoomout** of the map? ,as soon as possible so as it would help us for releasing the app to stores.

Comment: How do you zoom out? Using touch or programmatically? Do you have a crash log?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "zoom" method of the mapview. Referance http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Map.View-method-zoom
A positive value increases the current zoom level and a negative value decreases the zoom level. Each increase in zoom level increases the magnification by a factor of two.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.